# C# anonymous type foreach looping

Tags: c#, forms, c#-3.0, anonymous-types, business-logic-layer

I need to loop through the properties of a custom object type that I'm getting back from the database and only show the columns that contain data.
This means I cannot simply bind the list of objects to the datagrid.
I don't want to loop through each object and see if the column is empty/null and determine in the UI to display it.
What I'm thinking is in my business layer before I send the object back I would send an IEnumerable back with only those columns that should be visible.  Thus I was thinking of using Linq to Object to do this, but I'm not sure that would be very pretty.

Does anyone know of a solution that I could use without a ton of IF statements that I could do to check through a large object (30 or so columns) to determine what should be shown or not.

```
Foreach (CustomerData customerdata in Customers) 
{ 
    if (!customerdata.address.Equals("")) 
       {
            dgvCustomerData.Column["Address"].visible = false;
         }
        //Continue checking other data columns...
}
```

I wish to avoid all of this in the UI and all the IFs...
I'm having a brain fart on this one can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [the .NET Reflection Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(VS.71).aspx).  You can use reflection to get ahold of all of an object's properties, and loop through them to find out if they are null or not.  Then you could return a collection of KeyValuePair objects where Key = property name, and Value = true/false. You'd then use the keyvaluepairs to set column visibility...

Comment: This was more of the solution I was thinking, but instead of a hashtable, I was thinking more of an IEnumerable list that I could then simply bind to the datagrid.  I will research this a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following to simplify it a bit

```
Action<T,string> del = (value,name) => {
  if ( value.Equals("") ) {
    dgvCustomerData.Column[name].Visible = false;
  }
};
foreach ( var data in Customers ) {
  del(data.address,"Address");
  del(data.name, "Name");
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'd like to pull this out of the UI layer so that the UI doesn't have to decide what to show or not.  However, this was the approach I was thinking of doing in the first place.