# Loop Through LINQ Query Columns (Not rows)

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible, and if so how, to loop though the results of a LINQ query?

Something like this:

```
var results= from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where a.Field<int>("id") == i 
                    select new 
                    {
                       id= a.Field<int>("id"),
                       a= a.Field<double>("a"),
                       b = a.Field<double>("b")
                    };

IEnumerable<string> colNames = results.First().GetType().GetProperties()
                                                        .Select(p => p.Name);

string[] columns = colNames.ToArray();

int i = 0;
foreach (var row in results)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count(); i++)
    {
        string foobar = (string)row[columns[i]];
        i++;
    }
}
```

Essentially, I want to replicate the following sort of functionality:

```
DataRow dr = new DataRow();
string foobar = dr[columns[i];
```

Comment: You have to cast, so `string foobar = (string)dr[columns[i];

Comment: maybe this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882935/c-sharp-anonymous-type-foreach-looping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the option of changing your original LINQ statement to produce a data structure that allows you to do what you're looking for, I'd definitely suggest that.

If not, you'll need to use reflection to look up the properties of your anonymous type by their name, and then get the values of those properties by reflection:

```
    PropertyInfo[] columns = results.First().GetType().GetProperties();
    ...
            string foobar = columns[i].GetValue(row, null);
```

Comment: I havent really got the option no.  However, i have used a bit of reflection to get the properties, i just dont know what to do with them now!

Answer (score 3):

```
Action<string> processColumName = (cname) => 
                           { 
                              // do anything you want with a column name
                              string foo = (string) Row[cname]; 
                           };

results.First()
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Select(p => p.Name)
        .ToList().ForEach(processColumName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well my answer actually is based on [stovroz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038402/linq-loop-through-columns-in-row-c-sharp/24040061#24040061) from another question, slightly modified:

So here is the code:

```
foreach(var item in db.Products) {
   System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] fields = Product.GetType().GetProperties(); 
   foreach(var f in fields) {
      Console.WriteLine(f.Name + ": " + f.GetValue(item));
   }  
}
```